# How can I wait for a QWidget to close using QTestLib? [Qt5]

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtestlib, qsignalspy

I am writing a `QTest` based test case for a class that derives from `QWidget`.

After showing the widget, I want the test to **end as soon as the widget is closed**.

My first attempt was to use `QSignalSpy`, only to find out that `QWidget` really does not send out a signal on `close()`.

So what is the "right way" to do this using `QTest` primitives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you [specify](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setAttribute) [Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute for the widget and wait on its [destroyed()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#destroyed) signal?

```
pMyTestWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
pMyTestWidget->show();

// test thread...
QSignalSpy watchDog(pMyTestWidget, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)));
watchDog.wait();
```